# AWS, Bandwidth and SSD

Tags: amazon-web-services, bandwidth

I am using AWS T2.large instance for my rails application which has both API and CMS. I would like to change the instance type as it is consuming more memory. so which instance is suitable for my requirement along with pricing details of Bandwidth and SSD

Requirement: over 25k users can access the server parallelly

Comment: It isn't possible to estimate your resource requirements based on statistics like 25k users accessing the server.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot what are the things to estimate, I will  let you know